# Отключить запоминание полей Firefox

Tags: firefox

Как отключить запоминание полей в Firefox Developer Edition?
Имеется ввиду не логин и пароль, а все поля на странице включая чекбоксы и радио. Это раздражает.

Comment: речь про то, что заполнил ты форму какую то сохранил, а потом когда в следующий раз вернулся на страницу, то браузер вписал данные в поля, и натыкал галок сам?

Comment: _"Приватность и защита - История - Помнить историю поиска и данных форм"_, это немного не то наверное?

Comment: Более тонкая настройка - about:config.

Comment: @teran нет, это не то.

Comment: @nick_n_a Все параметры которые касаются autofill в положении false